# CakePHP redirect after changing language on edit/view action

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

im building an application in cakephp in multilingual, so for example when i am on homepage of application and i change the language it changes ok, but the problems appear when i am on an edit or view part for example:

```
example.com/en/item/edit/1
```

and i change language from en to it in the edit view it redirects to:

```
example.com/it/item/edit
```

but it doesent keep the passed parameter as it supposed to.

what should i do to make it work????

the link that i use to change lanugages are:

```
<?php
    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>". $this->Html->link('English', array('language'=>'en')) . "</li>"; 
    echo "<li>". $this->Html->link('Italian', array('language'=>'it')). "</li>";
    echo "<li>". $this->Html->link('German', array('language'=>'de')). "</li>";
    echo "<li>". $this->Html->link('Franch', array('language'=>'fr')). "</li>";
    echo "<li>". $this->Html->link('Spanish', array('language'=>'es')). "</li>";
    echo "<li>". $this->Html->link('Russian', array('language'=>'ru')). "</li>";
    echo "<li>". $this->Html->link('Chinesse', array('language'=>'zh')). "</li>";
    echo "<li>". $this->Html->link('Portuguese', array('language'=>'pt')). "</li>";
    echo "<ul>";
?>
```

The rout that i use are:

```
/*** Languages */
Router::connect('/:language',array('controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'index','home'),array('language' => '[a-z]{2}'));
Router::connect('/:language/:controller',array('controller' => 'pages','action' => 'index'),array('language' => '[a-z]{2}'));
Router::connect('/:language/:controller/:action/*', array('controller' => 'pages','action' => null), array('language' => '[a-z]{2}'));
```

And the function on the AppController that i call in beforeFilter is:

```
private function _setLanguage() {
        if ($this->Cookie->read('lang') && !$this->Session->check('Config.language')) {
            $this->Session->write('Config.language', $this->Cookie->read('lang'));

        } else if (isset($this->params['language']) && ($this->params['language'] !=  $this->Session->read('Config.language'))){
            $this->Session->write('Config.language', $this->params['language']);
            $this->Cookie->write('lang', $this->params['language'], false, '2 days');
        }
    }
```

Also i have overwriten the redirect method as follow on AppController:

```
public function redirect( $url, $status = NULL, $exit = true ) {
    if (!isset($url['language']) && $this->Session->check('Config.language')) {
        $url['language'] = $this->Session->read('Config.language');
    }
    parent::redirect($url,$status,$exit);
}
```

Comment: I haven't used routes a lot but 

Router::connect('/:language/:controller/:action/*', array('controller' => 'pages','action' => null), array('language' => '[a-z]{2}'));

looks to me like the id number is missing. So it doeas exactly what you tell it: 

example.com/it/item/edit 
instead of 

example.com/it/item/edit/1

If that cannot be fixed disable the language change for edit and views. That is cheating I know ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change all your language switching links to be similar to this:

```
$passedArgs = $this->request->params['named'] + $this->request->params['pass'];

$this->Html->link('English', array('language'=>'en') + $passedArgs);
```